# How to concatenate a dynamic variable on to a object path

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an object of objects using Angular, and `categoryOne`'s content is automatically loaded on my page. If a button is clicked, I want to call a function in my controller--that would be the `loadContent` function below the object of objects--to remove `categoryOne`'s content from the page and inject `categoryTwo`'s content in its place.

In my `loadContent` function, I want to target each object of `categoryTwo`'s `content` object. In other words, `$scope.layout.categories.categoryTwo.content.contentX.text` where "X" could be 1 or 2.

The thing is, I cannot find anything on the web about concatenating a dynamic variable on to a "path" that is targeting stuff in an object. In the paragraph above, "X" is the dynamic variable and this "path" I'm referring to is the stuff I'm trying to grab from my object of objects, if that makes sense.

**tl;dr** How can I concatenate a dynamic variable on to a path that is trying to grab stuff from an object of objects?

Thank you so much for helping me. Virtual high fives for all of you.

```
var app = angular.module("app1", []).controller("appCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.layout = 
    {
        "name": "test_proj",
        "title": "Test Project",
        "categories":
        {
            "categoryOne":
            {
                "heading": "Category 1",
                "links":
                {
                    "link1": "www.domain.com"
                },
                "content":
                {
                    "content1":
                    {
                        "text": "This is some text.",
                        "help": "Help text 1."
                    },
                    "content2":
                    {
                        "text": "Apples.",
                        "help": "Help text 2."
                    }
                }
            },
            "categoryTwo":
            {
                "heading": "Category 2",
                "links":
                {
                    "link1": "www.generic.com"
                },
                "content":
                {
                    "content1":
                    {
                        "text": "More text here.",
                        "help": "Help text 1."
                    },
                    "content2":
                    {
                        "text": "Oranges.",
                        "help": "Help text 2."
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    $scope.loadContent = function()
    {
        var catLength = 0;

        for (var key in $scope.layout.categories.categoryTwo.content)
        {
            if ($scope.layout.categories.categoryTwo.content.hasOwnProperty(key))
            {
                ++catLength;
            }
        }

        $(".cool-container").html("");

        for (var x = 0; x < catLength; x++)
        {
            $(".cool-container").append("<p class='content'>" + $scope.layout.categories.categoryTwo.content.contentX.text + "</p>");
            // Where it says "contentX" in the line above, I want "X" to be a dynamic variable that will make it "content1" and "content2"
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `$scope.layout.categories.categoryTwo.content["content" + X].text`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: This did it! I tried ...content.content[x].text but that produced an error of undefined. This, however, did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use bracket syntax instead of dot syntax if you need a dynamic object accessor:

E.g.

```
object['content' + x]
```

Read More:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: This worked! Sadly, @carebdayrvis answered first with the same answer, so they get the correct answer. Seriously, though, thanks!